# CakePhp lots and lots of dropdowns

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a huge form that I will split up in sections. Each section will have it's own model. I have an incredible amount of dropdowns. They are kinda similar so what I'd like to do is to be able to add options to them by calling a php variable. It would ensure I there's no typo and if a change is needed I can change it at one place.

If I have a language dropdown like so:

```
echo $this->Form->input(__('Language'), array(
    'options' => array('en' => 'English', 'fr' => 'Français')
));
```

Would be nice if I could do $this->Form->input(__('Language'), $languages); and then in $language I could have added those languages with a variable as well. $languages = array('options' => $option1, $option2...); something like that.

I'm just trying to find the best way to manage 1000 of dropdowns.

How could I do that?

Comment: please clarify - they have their own model, and that's the issue, or you're just trying to do a many-language dropdown managed by a database?  need to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppController set the language options in the beforeRender callback:-

```
public function beforeRender() {

    parent::beforeRender();

    $this->set('languages', array('en' => 'English', 'fr' => 'Français'));

}
```

Then in the relevant views you can just use:-

```
$this->Form->input(__('Language'), $languages);
```

It may make sense to create a Language model and store your languages in that and load them by using a find('list') on the model. If your other models need to be linked to a language you'd then have use a `$belongsTo = array('Language')` relationship on the relevant models and save the `language_id` for the model. All your language data would then be stored in the database for you to alter in one place.

Comment: The thing I can have something like Construction Material drop down with 10ish options but on another section have only 7 options. There's probably 100 Construction material drop down. Not sure if DB or just model would be the best option here. I'm thinking no DB and load each option independently in each dropdown instead of defining each complete dropdown. In the DB I guess it would store the id which would be a key in the .po file...

Comment: You could always use a joins table to define which of the options are available to a particular model. Keeping these in the database will make it easier to maintain in the future. Hard coding may cause you issues later on.

Comment: I was thinking something like CodeSet table and CodeSetItems table. A Code set is made up of one or many code set items. I guess that would work. I'll need a cross table to match them up.

Comment: How do I go about the models if I have something like this:
Codesets (id, label)
Codesetitems (id, text)
Dropdown (id , codeset_id, codesetitem_id)

Dropdown is the cross table to match the codeset with the codesetitem. How do the relationships work?

Comment: @Chris your joins table (what you've called Dropdown) should really be called codesets_codesetitems to keep consistent with CakePHP's naming convention (going away from this will give you all sorts of headaches). Then in your Codeset model you want $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Codesetitem'); and your Codesetitem model $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Codeset');. You don't need a model for the joins table. See the CakePHP manual for details http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm